# Qt: Hower effect overlapped with selected tab

Tags: css, qt, tabs, hover, widget

I have a tab widget in my Qt application and I designed it for myself with CSS.

This is how it looks like:

[image: The selected tab, 2. the hovered hab, 3. the inactive (unselected) tab]

*1. The selected tab, 2. the hovered tab, 3. the inactive (unselected) tab*

But when I hover over an already selected tab (in this case 'Create quiz'), it gets replaced with the hover effect (I forgot to use the black font color) I don't want that the user can hover on a selected tab. 'Create quiz' should stay green, even if you hover over it. But I also don't want to throw away the hover effect because it's useful.

[image: Hover effect is replacing the selected tab effect]

CSS:

```
QTabBar::tab{
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 94);
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
min-width: 8px;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-top: 4px;
margin-bottom: 2px;}


QTabBar::tab:selected {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(11, 154, 111);
}

QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 178);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one more section:

```
QTabBar::tab:selected:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(11, 154, 111);
}
```

Then selcted+hover will have green too. (or you can customize)